# Flutter - Left to Right Linear Background Animation

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, background, flutter-animation

I would like to create a background animation with clouds moving from the left side of the screen to the right side in a straight line

[cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzHsG.png)

```
What I'm currently using is a random generator 

 

ParticleOptions particleOptions = ParticleOptions(
        image: Image.asset('images2/cloud.png'),
        spawnOpacity: 0.2,
        opacityChangeRate: 0.4,
        minOpacity: 0.2,
        maxOpacity: 1,
        spawnMinSpeed: 10.0,
        spawnMaxSpeed: 30.0,
        spawnMinRadius: 15.0,
        spawnMaxRadius: 30.0,
        particleCount: 20,
      );
    
    AnimatedBackground(
            behaviour: RandomParticleBehaviour(options: particleOptions),
            vsync: 

this,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[Random Cloud Generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Dn8.png)

I tried the RacingLinesBehavior, however I can't customize it to custom images

So if you have an implementation or know of a package that would help that would be appreciated!